# Unable to create request to API with python requests. Even when all headers are correct

Tags: python, python-requests, http-headers, python-requests-html

I am trying to get a request https://api.dex.guru/v1/tokens/0x7060d3F1CC70A07f4768560B9D9B692ac29244dE using python. I have tried tons of different things but they all respond with 403 error forbidden. I have tried everything I can think of and have googled with no success.

currently my code for this request looks like this:

```
headers = {
    'authority': 'api.dex.guru',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'sec-ch-ua': '^\\^',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cookie': (cookies are here)
}

response = requests.get('https://api.dex.guru/v1/tradingview/symbols?symbol=0x7060d3f1cc70a07f4768560b9d9b692ac29244de-bsc', headers=headers)
```

then i print out response and it is a 403 error. Please help, I need this data for a project.

Comment: try the endpoint at the API source and see if it works: https://api.dex.guru/

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon.

I have managed to get this to work with the help of another user on Reddit.

The key to getting this API call to work is to use the cloudscraper module :-

```js
import cloudscraper
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()  # returns a CloudScraper instance
print(scraper.get("https://api.dex.guru/v1/tokens/0x8076C74C5e3F5852037F31Ff0093Eeb8c8ADd8D3-bsc").text)
```

This gave me a 200 response with the expected JSON content (substitute my URL above with yours and you should get the expected 200 response).

Many thanks
Jimmy

Answer (score 0):

I tried messing around with this myself, it appears your site has some sort of DDOS protection from Cloudflare blocking these API calls.  I'm not an expert in Python or headers by any means, so you might be supplying something to deal with that.  However I looked on their [website](https://docs.dex.guru/api) and it seems like the API is still in development.  Finally, I was getting 503 errors instead, and I was able to access the API normally through my browser.  Happy to tinker around more with this if you don't mind explaining what some of the cookies/headers are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the body of the response (`response.content` or `response.text`) as that might give you a more clear picture of why you get blocked.

For me it looks like they do some filtering based on the `user-agent`. I do get a Cloudflare DoS protection page (with a HTTP 503 response for example). Using a user-agent string that suggests that JavaScript won't work I do get a HTTP 200:

```
headers = {"User-Agent": "HTTPie/2.4.0"}
r = requests.get("https://api.dex.guru/v1/tokens/0x7060d3F1CC70A07f4768560B9D9B692ac29244dE", headers=headers)
```